# column index and column name based on a specific value

Tags: r

I want to identify column names and index based upon a specific value. Here is my sample dataframe -

```
set.seed(1)
age_range = sample(c("ar2-15", "ar16-29", "ar30-44"), 200, replace = TRUE)
gender = sample(c("M", "F",-999), 200, replace = TRUE)
region = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 200, replace = TRUE)
physi = sample(c("Poor", "Average", "Good"), 200, replace = TRUE)
height = sample(c(4,5,6,-999), 200, replace = TRUE)
height2 = sample(c(40,0), 200, replace = TRUE)
weight2 = sample(c(20,0,-999), 200, replace = TRUE)

survey = data.frame(age_range, gender, region,physi,height,height2,weight2)
head(survey)
```

How can I find the column names and indices in survey df where -999 exists? I tried using some combination of apply and which, but it did not work. Obviously I am doing something wrong.

EDIT:

```
> apply(survey,2,function(x) match(-999,x))
age_range    gender    region     physi    height   height2   weight2 
       NA        10        NA        NA         1        NA         2
```

This only gives me all column names and shows NA for the ones that don't have -999. Any pointers are highly appreciated. Thanks!
Jennifer

Comment: Are these -999 values supposed to be missing values? R has a special value `NA` for that. There are functions like `complete.cases` that will find missing values for you.

Comment: d.b - I need the column indices and names. Running your code gives me this - > which(survey == -999, arr.ind = TRUE)
       row col
  [1,]  10   2
  [2,]  11   2
which is not what I want. Thanks.

Comment: MrFlick - no. it can be any value.

Comment: whoever is downvoting the question...please constructively comment on what is wrong for everyone's benefit.

Comment: Do you want something like this: `df <- sapply(survey, function (x) ifelse(x == -999, 1, 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of d.b.'s comment I created this short line of code which does what I want. Thank you Stackoverflow community!

```
q=unique(data.frame(which(survey == -999, arr.ind = TRUE))[2])[1]$col

q # 2 5 7

names(survey[,q]) # [1] "gender"  "height"  "weight2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `lappply` `which` give you what you want? It will return a list of your column names, each item of which contains the indices where that element = -999

```
lapply(survey,function(x) which(x==-999))
```

Comment: Thanks Pdubbs...it gets me closer but not exactly what am looking for.